# This weird behaviour from cronjob

Tags: cron, crontab, cronjob

I have set the `crontab` like this:

```
*/5 0 * * * /www/permitChat.sh
```

and the **`/www/permitChat.sh`** is this:

```
# We are setting the name of file
# in the variable along with complete path.
sFilePath=`date +\/www\/ChatLogs\/%Y\/%m/%d_%m_%Y.txt`
# First we set its permissions to
# readable by all users, and then
# modify them to be writable by only root.
chmod a=r $sFilePath
chmod u+w $sFilePath
ls -lh $sFilePath
```

The trouble I am facing is, the cron gets executed after 12:00 PM everyday, instead of executing at 12:00 AM to 01:00 AM, every 5 minutes.

What could be wrong? All my system variables appear to be synced.

Comment: Is your system time correct?

Comment: Yes. The `date` command displays: **Thu Oct 4 02:31:13 IST 2012**

Comment: It’s good that the `date` command works _for you_, but do you know whether the system (specifically, the `cron` process) is running with the same time zone as you?

Comment: @Scott How do I check that?

Comment: Umm...  Put a `date` command (with output to somewhere you can see it, like a log file) into a `cron` job.  Make sure you aren’t sourcing your `.profile` or anything that would set up _your_ environment.  Also, there’s probably some config file you could look in, but even if I knew what OS you were using, I wouldn’t be able to tell you where it is without doing research that’s probably easier for you to do.

Comment: I've added a `date >> ~/log.txt` to the script. Will put up the output here.